# How to apply two inclusive filters in Angular?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

```
<tr ng-repeat="thing in things| filter: {toDpt: filterReceived} && {fromDpt: filterSent}">
```

I'm trying to show things from AND to my department(dpt). My filterReceived and filterSent are being toggled with two buttons. Both are working.

The problem is: only the first filter is working. If I put fromDpt before toDpt, only fromDpt will work.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: `filter:{toDpt: filterReceived, fromDpt: filterSent}`

Comment: This worked the same way as my sintaxe. The filter will apply on toDpt AND on fromDpt, I want to retrieve things that are toDpt OR fromDpt.

For example, I want to select filterReceived='Korea' and filterSent='Spain'.
With this TWO filters applied, I want to receive ALL things received by Korea and ALL things sent by Spain.
I don't want to receive ONLY things that were sent by Spain and received by Korea.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. OTOH, you had AND in capitals in the question, when in fact you want OR. You need to use a function as the filter value, and that function must return true if the thing is from one of the departments, and false otherwise.

Comment: Sorry too, I'm very bad at explaining things. Thanks, I'll make a function. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The goal os this code was to display tickets from department or to deparment. The $scope.filters contains the filters to be applied. A user can see, simultaneously or not, tickets that his department has sent or received.

Using Angular Filters, I was able to call my ticketsFilter function, passing in the tickets as the first default argument and filters as second optional argument.

Controller:

```
$scope.filters.toDpt = 'Finance';
$scope.filters.fromDpt = 'Food';
```

Filter:

```
app.filter('ticketsFilter', function (){
    return function (items, filters){
        console.log
        var filtered = [];
        for (var i=0; i < items.length; i++){
            var item = items[i];
            //CHECKING FROM AND TO DPT.
            if (item.fromDpt == filters.sent){
                filtered.push(item);
            } else if (item.toDpt == filters.received){
                filtered.push(item);
            };
        };
        return filtered;
    };
});
```

Markup:

```
<tr ng-repeat="ticket in tickets | ticketsFilter:filters">
```